# Simple Poker Game

Tags: javascript, game, node.js, playing-cards

I'm building a simple Poker game. It is almost complete, but I want to refactor it early.

- To calculate hand strength / ranks, I use this library from NPM: [poker-evaluator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/poker-evaluator)
- For deck shuffling, I use the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

My code is mainly about game-play, determine if ready to start next round, determine whose turn it is, etc. I want to make this code more readable, easy to maintain, and not too difficult to understand for other programmers. Any suggestions?

**index.js** (usage)

```
var Game = require('./src/game');
var game = new Game();

game.addPlayer({
    name: "A",
    chips: 40000
});
game.addPlayer({
    name: "B",
    chips: 20000
});
game.addPlayer({
    name: "C",
    chips: 20000
});

game.start();

game.getCurrentPlayer().callOrCheck();      // A
game.getCurrentPlayer().callOrCheck();      // B
game.getCurrentPlayer().raise(2000);        // C
game.getCurrentPlayer().raise(2000);        // A
game.getCurrentPlayer().fold();             // B
game.getCurrentPlayer().callOrCheck();      // C
game.getCurrentPlayer().callOrCheck();      // A
game.getCurrentPlayer().raise(1000);        // C
game.getCurrentPlayer().callOrCheck();      // A
game.getCurrentPlayer().callOrCheck();      // C
game.getCurrentPlayer().raise(3000);        // A
game.getCurrentPlayer().callOrCheck();      // C
game.getCurrentPlayer().callOrCheck();      // A
game.getCurrentPlayer().callOrCheck();      // C
```

**Results in console:**

> ```
> Player A added to the game
> Player B added to the game
> Player C added to the game
> Game reset
> ========== STARTING GAME ==========
>     Player A gets card : As & 4c
> Player B gets card : Th & 2s
> Player C gets card : 5c & 7s
> Player A is the dealer
> Player B pays small blind : 1000
> Player C pays big blind : 2000
> Now its player A's turn
> ========== Round DEAL ==========
>     Player A CALL : 2000
> cannot begin next round
> Player B CALL : 1000
> cannot begin next round
> Player C Raises : 2000
> cannot begin next round
> Player A Raises : 4000
> cannot begin next round
> Player B FOLD
> cannot begin next round
> Player C CALL : 2000
> begin next round
> Total Pot : 14000
> ========== Round FLOP ==========
>     Community cards : Ad, Qh, 6h
> Player A CHECK
> cannot begin next round
> Player C Raises : 1000
> cannot begin next round
> Player A CALL : 1000
> begin next round
> Total Pot : 16000
> ========== Round TURN ==========
>     Community cards : Ad, Qh, 6h, 3d
> Player C CHECK
> cannot begin next round
> Player A Raises : 3000
> cannot begin next round
> Player C CALL : 3000
> begin next round
> Total Pot : 22000
> ========== Round RIVER ==========
>     Community cards : Ad, Qh, 6h, 3d, 8d
> Player A CHECK
> cannot begin next round
> Player C CHECK
> begin next round
> Total Pot : 22000
> ========== SHOWDOWN ==========
>     Community cards : Ad, Qh, 6h, 3d, 8d
> Player A : As, 4c | strength : 10972 | one pair
> Player B : Th, 2s | strength : 5165 | high card
> Player C : 5c, 7s | strength : 5124 | high card
> Player A wins with one pair
> ```

**game.js**

```js
module.exports = Game;

var Player = require('./player.js');
var Deck = require('./deck.js');
var PokerEvaluator = require('poker-evaluator');

var debug = true;
function logd(message) {
    if (debug) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}

function Game() {
    // Game attributes
    this.BET = 2000;

    this.players = [];          // array of Player object, represents all players in this game
    this.round = 'idle';        // current round in a game
    this.dealerPos = 0;         // to determine the dealer position for each game, incremented by 1 for each end game
    this.turnPos = 0;           // to determine whose turn it is in a playing game
    this.pot = 0;               // accumulated chips in center of the table
    this.communityCards = [];   // array of Card object, five cards in center of the table
    this.deck = new Deck();     // deck of playing cards
}

/**
 * Adds new player to the game
 * @param attr
 */
Game.prototype.addPlayer = function(attr) {
    var newPlayer = new Player(attr);
    logd('Player ' + newPlayer.name + ' added to the game');
    newPlayer.game = this;
    this.players.push(newPlayer);
};

/**
 * Resets game to the default state
 */
Game.prototype.reset = function() {
    logd('Game reset');
    this.round = 'idle';
    this.communityCards = [];   // clear cards on board
    this.pot = 0;               // clear pots on board
    this.deck = new Deck();     // use new deck of cards
    for (var i=0; i<this.players.length; i++) {
        this.players[i].reset();
    }
};

/**
 * Starts the 'deal' Round
 */
Game.prototype.start = function() {
    this.reset();
    logd('========== STARTING GAME ==========');

    // deal two cards to each players
    for (var i=0; i<this.players.length; i++) {
        var c1 = this.deck.drawCard();
        var c2 = this.deck.drawCard();
        logd('Player ' + this.players[i].name + ' gets card : ' + c1 + ' & ' + c2);
        this.players[i].firstCard = c1;
        this.players[i].secondCard = c2;
    }

    // determine dealer, small blind, big blind
    // modulus with total number of players
    // numbers will back to 0 if exceeds the number of players
    logd('Player ' + this.players[this.dealerPos].name + ' is the dealer');
    var smallBlindPos = ( this.dealerPos+1 ) % this.players.length;
    var bigBlindPos = ( this.dealerPos+2 ) % this.players.length;

    // small and big pays blind
    this.players[smallBlindPos].addBet(1/2 * this.BET);
    this.players[bigBlindPos].addBet(this.BET);

    logd('Player ' + this.players[smallBlindPos].name + ' pays small blind : ' + (1/2 * this.BET));
    logd('Player ' + this.players[bigBlindPos].name + ' pays big blind : ' + this.BET);

    // determine whose turn it is
    this.turnPos = ( bigBlindPos+1 ) % this.players.length;
    logd('Now its player ' + this.players[this.turnPos].name + '\'s turn');

    // begin game, start 'deal' Round
    logd('========== Round DEAL ==========');
    this.round = 'deal';
};

Game.prototype.incrementPlayerTurn = function() {
    do {
        this.turnPos = ( this.turnPos+1 ) % this.players.length;
    } while(this.players[this.turnPos].hasDone);
};

/**
 * Check if ready to begin new round
 * Round ends when all players' bet are equal,
 * With exception Fold and All-in players
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
Game.prototype.isEndRound = function() {
    var endOfRound = true;
    //For each player, check
    for(var i=0; i<this.players.length; i++) {
        var plyr = this.players[i];
        if (!plyr.hasActed && !plyr.hasDone) {
            endOfRound = false;
        }
    }
    return endOfRound;
};

/**
 * Play the next round
 */
Game.prototype.nextRound = function() {
    if (this.round === 'idle') {
        this.start();
    } else if (this.round === 'deal') {
        this.gatherBets();
        this.flop();
    } else if (this.round === 'flop') {
        this.gatherBets();
        this.turn();
    } else if (this.round === 'turn') {
        this.gatherBets();
        this.river();
    } else if (this.round === 'river') {
        this.gatherBets();
        this.showdown();
    } else {
        this.start();
    }
};

/**
 * Checks if ready to next round
 * If yes, starts the next round
 */
Game.prototype.checkForNextRound = function() {
    if (this.isEndRound()) {
        logd('begin next round');
        this.nextRound();
    } else {
        logd('cannot begin next round');
    }
};

/**
 * Starts the 'flop' Round
 */
Game.prototype.flop = function() {
    logd('========== Round FLOP ==========');
    this.round = 'flop';
    // deal three cards in board
    this.communityCards[0] = this.deck.drawCard();
    this.communityCards[1] = this.deck.drawCard();
    this.communityCards[2] = this.deck.drawCard();
    // begin betting
    logd('Community cards : ' + this.communityCards[0] + ', ' + this.communityCards[1] + ', ' + this.communityCards[2]);
    // other players must act
    this.requestPlayerAction();
};

/**
 * Starts the 'turn' Round
 */
Game.prototype.turn = function() {
    logd('========== Round TURN ==========');
    this.round = 'turn';
    // deal fourth card
    this.communityCards[3] = this.deck.drawCard();
    // begin betting
    logd('Community cards : ' + this.communityCards[0] + ', ' + this.communityCards[1] + ', ' + this.communityCards[2] + ', ' + this.communityCards[3]);
    // other players must act
    this.requestPlayerAction();
};

/**
 * Starts the 'river' Round
 */
Game.prototype.river = function() {
    logd('========== Round RIVER ==========');
    this.round = 'river';
    // deal fifth card
    this.communityCards[4] = this.deck.drawCard();
    // begin betting
    logd('Community cards : ' + this.communityCards[0] + ', ' + this.communityCards[1] + ', ' + this.communityCards[2] + ', ' + this.communityCards[3] + ', '  + this.communityCards[4]);
    // other players must act
    this.requestPlayerAction();
};

/**
 * Starts the 'showdown' Round
 */
Game.prototype.showdown = function() {
    logd('========== SHOWDOWN ==========');
    this.round = 'showdown';
    // gather all hands
    var hands = [];
    for (var i=0; i<this.players.length; i++) {
        hands.push([
            this.players[i].firstCard,
            this.players[i].secondCard,
            this.communityCards[0],
            this.communityCards[1],
            this.communityCards[2],
            this.communityCards[3],
            this.communityCards[4]
        ]);
    }
    // evaluate all cards
    var evalHands = [];
    for (i=0; i<hands.length; i++) {
        evalHands.push(PokerEvaluator.evalHand(hands[i]));
    }
    logd('Community cards : ' + this.communityCards[0] + ', ' + this.communityCards[1] + ', ' + this.communityCards[2] + ', ' + this.communityCards[3] + ', '  + this.communityCards[4]);
    // get highest value
    var highestVal = -9999;
    var highestIndex = -1;
    for (i=0; i<evalHands.length; i++) {
        logd('Player ' + this.players[i].name + ' : ' + this.players[i].firstCard + ', ' + this.players[i].secondCard + ' | strength : ' + evalHands[i].value + ' | ' + evalHands[i].handName);
        if (highestVal < evalHands[i].value) {
            highestVal = evalHands[i].value;
            highestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    logd('Player ' + this.players[highestIndex].name + ' wins with ' + evalHands[highestIndex].handName);
};

/**
 * Get the highest bet from all players
 * @returns {number} highestBet
 */
Game.prototype.getHighestBet = function() {
    var highestBet = -999;
    for(var i=0; i<this.players.length; i++) {
        if (highestBet < this.players[i].bet) {
            highestBet = this.players[i].bet;
        }
    }
    return highestBet;
};

/**
 * Collect all bets from players to the board's pot
 */
Game.prototype.gatherBets = function() {
    for(var i=0; i<this.players.length; i++) {
        this.pot += this.players[i].bet;
        this.players[i].bet = 0;
    }
    logd("Total Pot : " + this.pot)
};

/**
 * returns the player whose current turn it is
 * @returns {Player}
 */
Game.prototype.getCurrentPlayer = function() {
    return this.players[this.turnPos];
};

/**
 * Sets all players' hasActed to false
 */
Game.prototype.requestPlayerAction = function() {
    for (var i=0; i<this.players.length; i++) {
        if (!this.players[i].hasDone) {
            this.players[i].hasActed = false;
        }
    }
};
```

**player.js**

```js
module.exports = Player;

var debug = true;
function logd(message) {
    if (debug) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}

function Player(options) {
    this.id = options.id;
    this.name = options.name;
    this.chips = options.chips;
    this.game = null;

    this.firstCard = {};
    this.secondCard = {};
    this.bet = 0;

    this.lastAction = "";
    this.hasActed = false;      // acted for one round (call/check/raise)
    this.hasDone = false;       // finish acted for one game (fold/allin)
}

/**
 * Folds the game
 */
Player.prototype.fold = function() {
    logd('Player ' + this.name + ' FOLD');

    this.lastAction = "fold";
    this.hasDone = true;

    this.game.incrementPlayerTurn();
    this.game.checkForNextRound();
};

/**
 * Puts all your chips to your bet
 */
Player.prototype.allin = function() {
    logd('Player ' + this.name + ' ALL-IN : ' + this.chips);

    this.lastAction = "allin";
    this.hasDone = true;

    this.addBet(this.chips);
    this.game.incrementPlayerTurn();
    this.game.checkForNextRound();
};

/**
 * Adds some chips to your bet
 * So that your bet is equal
 * With the highest bet in the table
 * If highest bet is 0, will do nothing
 */
Player.prototype.callOrCheck = function() {
    this.hasActed = true;

    var diff = this.game.getHighestBet() - this.bet;
    this.addBet(diff);

    if (diff > 0) {
        this.lastAction = "call";
        logd('Player ' + this.name + ' CALL : ' + diff);
    } else {
        this.lastAction = "check";
        logd('Player ' + this.name + ' CHECK');
    }
    this.game.incrementPlayerTurn();
    this.game.checkForNextRound();
};

/**
 * Raise your bet
 * If your bet is not the same with highest bet
 * Add to your bet altogether with difference
 * @param amount
 */
Player.prototype.raise = function(amount) {
    this.lastAction = "raise";

    var diff = this.game.getHighestBet() - this.bet;
    this.addBet(diff + amount);

    logd('Player ' + this.name + ' Raises : ' + (diff + amount));

    this.game.requestPlayerAction(); // other players must act
    this.hasActed = true;
    this.game.incrementPlayerTurn();
    this.game.checkForNextRound();
};

/**
 * Resets the player state
 */
Player.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.firstCard = {};
    this.secondCard = {};
    this.bet = 0;

    this.lastAction = "";
    this.hasActed = false;
    this.hasDone = false;
};

/**
 * Removes player's chip
 * Adds them to player's bet
 * @param amount
 */
Player.prototype.addBet = function(amount) {
    if (this.chips < amount) {
        return "error - not enough chips";
    }
    this.chips -= amount;
    this.bet += amount;
};
```

**deck.js**

```js
module.exports = Deck;

function Deck() {
    this.suits = [ 's', 'h', 'd', 'c' ];
    this.ranks = [ '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ];
    this.cards = [];

    this.init();
    this.shuffle();
}

Deck.prototype.init = function() {
    var suitsLen = this.suits.length;
    var ranksLen = this.ranks.length;
    var i, j;

    for (i=0; i<suitsLen; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<ranksLen; j++) {
            this.cards.push( this.ranks[j] + this.suits[i] );
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Fisher-Yates Shuffle
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array
 */
Deck.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var currentIndex = this.cards.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = this.cards[currentIndex];
        this.cards[currentIndex] = this.cards[randomIndex];
        this.cards[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
};

Deck.prototype.drawCard = function () {
    return this.cards.pop();
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something. I'm more of a beginner and was using your code as a reference for my own game. Nevertheless, I noticed that `lastAction` seems to be fairly pointless, and the way the showdown is structured seems to make it so that you can win even if you have folded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a once over:

- In `index.js` you keep using `game.getCurrentPlayer().`, since all those activities can only be done by the current player I feel the caller should just be able to just call `game.callOrCheck();` and `callOrCheck` then figures out who the current player is.
- You should use a common logger / output module instead of copy pasting in each module
- This might be overkill, but read up on [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you are mixing output and logic so much that you might regret it at some point
- Consider using a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/), it has a built-in function to shuffle arrays.

Other than that I like your code, I could not find much of any problem.